# TypeError at /formpage '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' also the error is specific in form.is_valid

Tags: django, django-forms

This is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

def check_for_z(value):
if value[0].lower() !='z':
    raise forms.ValidationError("NAME NEEDS TO START WITH Z")
class FormName(forms.Form):
name  = forms.CharField()
email = forms.EmailField()
text  = forms.CharField(widget= forms.Textarea)
botcatcher = forms.CharField(required=False,
                             widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                             validators=[validators.MaxValueValidator(0)])
```

This is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms
from .forms import FormName
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def index(request):
return render(request,'formapp/index.html')

def form_name_view(request):
form =  forms.FormName()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = forms.FormName(request.POST)

    if form .is_valid ():
        # do something code
        print("Validations scuces")
        print("NAME: "+form.cleaned_data["name"])
        print("EMAIL: "+form.cleaned_data["email"])
        print("TEXT:"+form.cleaned_data['text'])
        # return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
    else:
        form= FormName()
return render(request,'formapp/form_page.html',{'form' : form})
```

Now actually it is throwing error on the line ***form.is_valid()***
and is showing ***TypeError at /formpage
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'***

And this is happening when I change/add attribute in the botcatcher i.e i add value='joke'

Everything else is similar to normal django

Comment: Using a `validators.MaxValueValidator(0)` on a `CharField` makes not much sense, since you can not compare a *string* with an *int*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator `MaxValueValidator(0)` and a `CharField` do not work well together, since a `CharField` will clean the value to a `str`ing, and you then compare it with an `int`.

You can use an `IntegerField` to check if the value is less than or equal to zero:

```
class FormName(forms.Form):
    name  = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    text  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    botcatcher = forms.IntegerField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.HiddenInput,
        validators=[validators.MaxValueValidator(0)]
    )
```

If you want to validate that the number is *positive*, you can use a [**`MinValidator`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.MinValueValidator), but it is easiler to make use of the [**`min_value=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.IntegerField.min_value) or [**`max_value=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.IntegerField.max_value) parameter of the `IntegerField`:

```
class FormName(forms.Form):
    name  = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    text  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    botcatcher = forms.IntegerField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.HiddenInput,
        min_value=0  # ← checks if it is a postive number
    )
```